# How to create a datatable gridview from a table inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gridview

I'm just a beginner and starting Jquery.I want to create a gridview with the below code. I created the table inside a div and called the jquery datatable script implement the gridview for the table:

```
<div id="cont-lef">
   <table align="center" cellpadding="5px" border="1" id="myGridStyle">
       <tr>
          <td><p>Sunday Mornings</td>          
          <td><p>Rs 2.5 lakhs + ST</td>          
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><p>Saturday &Sunday Afternoons</td>          
          <td><p>Rs 2.0 lakhs + ST</td>          
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><p>Weekdays  </td>
          <td><p>Rs 1.5 lakhs + ST</td>          
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><p>Tournament Management</td>          
          <td><p>Rs. 25,000 + ST</td>          
       </tr>        
       <tr>
          <td><p>Caddy Fee</td>          
          <td><p>Rs. 300 per caddy</td>          
       </tr>                     
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){ $("#myGridStyle").dataTable(); })
    </script>
    <p>
        <i>*Catering to be negotiated directly with caterer</i>
    </p>
</div>
```

Now, why is it not creating the datatable gridview when I have done exactly what as it is in the example.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NjRLm/)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the css file...
here's the demo [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NjRLm/5/)

```
<link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

also refer [link](http://live.datatables.net/welcome/1/edit)